# Pushing references into a vector, are references valid after function exits?

Tags: c++, memory-management, memory-leaks

I create a vector of pointers to double array. Are these pointers valid after function (i.e. `InsertIntoVector`) exits? If I later fetch the pointer as in `GetVecElement`, are the pointers still guaranteed to point to the same memory location they were assigned?

```
class A { 
   vector<double*> vec; 

   void insertIntoVector(double x, double y); 
   void GetVecElement(int i, double& x, double& y); 
}; 

A::insertIntoVector(double x, double y) { 
   double* xy = new double[2]; 
   xy[0] = x; xy[1] = y; 
   vec.push_back(xy);       
}

A::GetVecElement(int i, double& x, double& y)
{
    x = vec[i][0];       // will the reference to the double array still be valid? 
    y = vec[i][1];
}
```

Comment: Those are not _references_! One can't have a vector of references... those are _pointers_

Comment: New to stackoverflow, but have now accepted previous answers. So sorry pointers yes ofcourse and not references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are not *references*! Those are *pointers*...

> If I later fetch the pointer as in GetVecElement, are the references still guaranteed to point to the same memory location they were assigned?

You are not deleting the pointer, and `std::vector` won't do it for you, so yes the pointers will remain valid. It will also be *leaked* unless you manually `delete` each of them at `A`'s destructor. But for that you will need a *copy-constructor* and an *assign-operator* as well, to clone the contents of the `vector`.

Comment: I dont quite understand leaking, so when my program quits the memory is still being held. But doesnt modern OS clean up the memory eventually? Should I be really worried about this lurking memory? I know its bad practice, but what are the consequences?

Comment: @dr_rk: The consequences of knowingly following bad practices is that of becoming a bad programmer, not to mention _lazy_...

Comment: Imagine that you clear your vector multiple times, then re-add more elements, then clear again (ad infinutum). The memory that you have allocated each time cannot be reused in the lifetime of your application (because you are not deleting it). This will result in memory fragmentation.

Comment: Would this work to clear the memory: `for (int i=0;i<vec.size();i++) delete[] vec[i];`

Comment: @dr_rk: Yes it will. Call that from your destructor.  And make proper copy/assignment operators.

Comment: @dr_rk: That works, as long as you don't remove pointers from the vector nor change them in any other way.

Answer (score 0):

The values you are acquiring via reference arguments using the GetVecElement function are the values of the array on the stack pointed to by the elements of your vector (that you have allocated in insertIntoVector(). As you are not deleting these anywhere in your code (or at least as it appears) these values will still persist but essentially what you have here is a memory leak unless you have some extra code that is cleaning up this memory and that you have not uploaded in your example. When your vector is deleted or cleared, the memory locations pointed to be the double* elements of the vector will persist unless you actively implement some code to clean it up (which would be a good idea).